# Can't change the background for UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem, uiappearance

I need to change the default (which was already declared in my AppDelegate) background for UIBarButtonItem in one ViewController.

So, In my AppDelegate I have:

```
UIImage *navBarItemBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar_button_green"];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBarItemBackground
                                            forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                          barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

And when I need to restore the default background for the button - I implement in my viewController:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
UIBarButtonItem *rightBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Сохранить" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(clickOnSend:)];
[rightBarItem setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""] forState:UIControlStateNormal style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarItem;
```

But I think that it's not correct to set the empty file as the image. Is there more simple way to implement this behaviour? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change only one or several `UIViewController's` `UIBarButtonItems` backgroundImage, you'd better change in the specific `UIViewController`s as the latter case you use. while `[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:forState:style:barMetrics:];`  will change all the `UIBarButtonItems` background image, which maybe not the better one.

Comment: Yes, the second part of the code is placed in separate viewController. But I need to left for this button the default iOS6 background and for all the rest buttons I need to change the background with the appearance.

Comment: @ShurupuS then you just pass nil to the image parameter, it should work.

Comment: Yes - it works, just tried to use this solution - no the code looks a little bit simpler. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code to this:

```
UIBarButtonItem * rightBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                           initWithTitle: @"Сохранить"
                                           style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                           target: nil action: nil];
UIImage *navBarItemBackground = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar_button_green"]resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 13, 0, 6)];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBarItemBackground
                                                forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                              barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem: rightBarItem];
```

Comment: I need to left default only one barButton in one viewController - the other buttons should be changed with the appearance.

Comment: Apply this code to change all butoons, and use specific code without [UIBarButtonItem appearance] to the viewController that needs the default one.